# XML Ribbon in Outlook - make it appear on a specific window

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, ribbon

I'm making my first attempt at creating a Ribbon in Outlook using XML and am having trouble locating specifically how to tell my add-in that I only want the ribbon to appear on Explorer windows.

Advice?

Thanks.

my Ribbon1.XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns">
        <group id="MyGroup"
               label="My Group">
          <button idMso="Delete"/>
        </group>
      </tab>
      <tab idMso="TabMail">
        <group idMso="GroupMoveActions"
               visible="false">
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

The magical error box that pops up says:

CustomUI Runtime Error in testingOLaddin2

```
Error found in CustomUI XML of "testingOLaddin2"

Line: 3
Column: 10
Error Code 0x80004005
Failed to find Office control by ID
ID: TabMail
```

Per request, my ribbon generation code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

using System.Diagnostics;

namespace testingOLaddin2
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Ribbon1 : Office.IRibbonExtensibility
    {
        private Office.IRibbonUI ribbon;

        public Ribbon1()
        {
        }

        #region IRibbonExtensibility Members

        public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
        {
            return GetResourceText("testingOLaddin2.Ribbon1.xml");
        }

        #endregion

        #region Ribbon Callbacks
        //Create callback methods here. For more information about adding callback methods, select the Ribbon XML item in Solution Explorer and then press F1

        public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
        {
            this.ribbon = ribbonUI;
        }


        #endregion

        #region Helpers

        private static string GetResourceText(string resourceName)
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string[] resourceNames = asm.GetManifestResourceNames();
            for (int i = 0; i < resourceNames.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (string.Compare(resourceName, resourceNames[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                {
                    using (StreamReader resourceReader = new StreamReader(asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceNames[i])))
                    {
                        if (resourceReader != null)
                        {
                            return resourceReader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone know how to solve this same error if you have an add-in built with Designer, instead of XML?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This depends on the method you use to create the addin and ribbon. If you are using the

```
IRibbonExtensibility.GetCustomUI(string RibbonId)
```

method you could accomplish this by only returning the ribbon xml if the RibbonId parameter has the value

```
"Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer"
```

**Edit**

Following change in your code might work:

```
public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
{
  if (ribbonID == "Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer")
    return GetResourceText("testingOLaddin2.Ribbon1.xml");

  return null; // if problems here, try return string.Empty
}
```

Comment: I see that code in the Ribbon1.cs file, but am not sure how to call it, nor do I know where to enter the proper code in the XML file.

Comment: GetCustomUI will be called by Outlook when it needs your ribbbon. It will tell you where it's gonna use it via the RibbonId parameter. You don't have to call the method. You just have to make sure it returns the proper result if Outlook asks it.

Comment: @Jan - how do I get that information?  That's where I'm getting lost

Comment: @Jan - i'm passing the GetCustomUI info to a public static string in my main application.  It returns all of the XML I've entered in my Ribbon1.xml.  I need to be able to separate the Inspector tabs from teh Explorer tabs, but I don't see how to do that in the one XML file.

Comment: @Larry - I updated my answer according to the information you added.

Comment: @Jan - I'll give it a shot later today/tomorrow and update you on the progress.  thanks.  btw - i was working from VS2010 template code.  this is the first time i've written a ribbon using xml directly

Answer (score 2):

Your `GetCustomUI(string RibbonId)` Is called by Outlook once you implemenent `CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()` in the `ThisAddIn` class to return a new instance of your ribbon class. The ribbon class is where you reference the XML (in `GetCustomUI`).

For the XML itself, you will need to reference each Outlook explorer type individually. Unfortunately, there isn't an overarching way to specify "all explorers" in the Ribbon XML syntax, as far as I know.

Here are some examples referencing the Mail and Calendar explorers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabCalendar">
      <!-- Calendar tab controls go here -->
      </tab>
      <tab idMso="TabMail">
      <!-- mail tab controls go here -->
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Microsoft does give some hint about `idMso` attributes for built-in tabs, but unfortunately it's buried in this Excel spreadsheet: [link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=4329d9e9-4d11-46a5-898d-23e4f331e9ae&displaylang=en)

Comment: I've been using the spreadsheets and have my info as listed, but my test code is giving me an error when I open up a new mail message that TabMail doesn't exist.  My button/group appears on the main explorer (where I want it) with no problems, though.

Comment: @Larry It's surprising that Outlook would be trying to reference TabMail (an explorer tab) when opening a new mail message (in an inspector). If possible, would you please post your GetCustomUI() and CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject() ?

Comment: will do in a few minutes.  About to post another question related to a different add-in.

Comment: @Larry Now that I see the error, I remember running into this problem. Is your "Show Add-in User Interface Errors" setting enabled in Outlook (details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx)? As you've found, Outlook applies the same ribbon definition to every inspector/explorer, generating errors when tabs referenced by idMso don't exist. We just turned off that setting. I haven't yet found a better solution.