# programmatically control ribbon in office add-in at runtime

Tags: outlook, ms-office, ribbon, office-addins

I am creating an Outlook add-in which is going to open a new window and collect some information before sending it as an email.

To get the Outlook layout I have tried to create a taskpane in the new email dialog which is only visible when the user clicks a custom button in the Explorer window.

Now I want to open a new mail and have a custom ribbon or just a tab when my custom button is clicked. This ribbon/tab should only be visible when the new email is loaded from my code. When the user clicks New Email the default ribbon must be loaded.

My problem is I can’t find a way to programmatically modify the ribbon at runtime.
As an alternative simply hiding the whole ribbon could be a solution.

I have searched everywhere and can’t either confirm or deny that it is possible to control the ribbon at runtime.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `IDTExtensibility2` and `IRibbonExtensibility` interfaces in the same class in your add-in in order to customize the ribbon interface in Outlook.

The `IRibbonExtensibility.GetCustomUI` method should return the XML that configures the ribbon - see MSDN for [a list of the IDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868522.aspx) for the different windows in Outlook, each with their separate ribbons. Based on the description in your question, I think the one you need is `Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose`.

See [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5983381/1490783) for a sample.

By implementing different callbacks in your code, the custom ribbon could then be designed to only be visible if your conditions are met.